# The rest of the task should not skip if BranchPythonOperator result is False

Tags: python, airflow

I have an Airflow DAG, that branches to whether to send an email or not. `will_send_email_task` is a BranchPythonOperator, that `if len(message) > 0`, it should go to the branch task `send_email_notification_task`. Otherwise, that task is skipped and will go straight to the DummyOperator `join_task`. The DAG works OK when the result of the branch is `True` (yes, it should send an email). However, the rest of the DAG is skipped when the result is `False`, which is not what the expected. The expected outcome if `will_send_email_task` is `False` should be that  only `send_email_notification_task` is skipped/bypassed, but the rest of the flow continue as normal.

[image: skipped DAG]

Here is the Airflow DAG snippet:

```
# this function determines whether to send an email or not
def will_send_email(push_task, **context):
    message = context["task_instance"].xcom_pull(task_ids=push_task)

    if len(message) > 0:
        logging.info(f"email body: {message}")
        context["task_instance"].xcom_push(key="message", value=message)
        return 'send_email_notification_task'
    else:
        return 'join_task'
        
def some_python_callable(table_name, **context):
    ...

will_send_email_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='will_send_email_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=will_send_email,
    op_kwargs={'push_task': 'some_previous_task'},
    dag=dag
)


join_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='join_task',
    dag=dag
)

send_email_notification_task = EmailOperator(
    task_id='send_email_notification_task',
    to=default_args['email'],
    subject="some email subject",
    html_content="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(key='message') }}",
    dag=dag
)

end_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='end_task',
    dag=dag
)

...

for table, val in some_dict.items():

    offload_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id = f"offload_{table}_task",
        dag=dag,
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=some_python_callable,
        op_kwargs={'table_name': table}
    )
    
    offload_task.set_upstream(join_task)
    offload_task.set_downstream(end_task)
```

How should I configure my DAG so it would still run as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set `trigger_rule='none_failed_min_one_success'` for the `join_task`:

```
join_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='join_task',
    dag=dag,
   trigger_rule='none_failed_min_one_success'
)
```

This is a use case which explained in trigger rules [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules).
The default trigger rule is `all_success` but in your case one of the upstream task of `join_task` is guaranteed to be skipped so you can not use the default trigger rule.

Note: For Airflow < 2.2 use `trigger_rule='none_failed_or_skipped'` `trigger_rule='none_failed_or_skipped'` The trigger rule was just renamed in later version as it's name was confusing (see [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17683)), you can also use `trigger_rule='all_done'`.